# Terminal starts with a 'mkdir' error

Tags: command-line, mkdir

I am a rookie in the Linux space, especially Ubuntu. For the past few days, I have been getting an error in the terminal every time I start the console. The error says

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/agrim/go’: File exists
```

Although, console works perfectly fine,but the error is really annoying. Can anyone please help me out with this ?

Comment: Whats the output of `grep -Hn 'mkdir.*go' ~/.bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc ~/.profile /etc/profile` ?

Comment: The output is - `/home/agrim/.bashrc:117:mkdir ~/go`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a warning, telling you that it's trying to create a directory that already exist.

As your output result is `/home/agrim/.bashrc:117:mkdir ~/go`

By removing the `mkdir ~/go` command in `/home/agrim/.bashrc` file (should be line 117) can help you to get rid of this issue.

That file can be edited with any text editor, e.g. `gedit /home/agrim/.bashrc`

Answer (score 3):

The output of

```
grep -Hn 'mkdir.*go' ~/.bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc ~/.profile /etc/profile
```

is

```
/home/agrim/.bashrc:117:mkdir ~/go
```

which means in your `~/.bashrc`, you have the command `mkdir ~/go` at line number 117, hence it is being run every time you are starting an interactive shell.

You need to remove that line to get rid of the warning.

You can:

- Use a text editor like `gedit`, `nano`, `vim` (whatever you prefer), go to line number 117 and remove the line (or put a `#` infront)
- Or use `sed` with pattern matching

  ```
  sed -i '/^mkdir[[:blank:]]\+~\/go$/ d' /home/agrim/.bashrc
  ```
- Or remove the specific line (line number 117) with `sed`:

  ```
  sed -i '117 d' /home/agrim/.bashrc
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your support. The problem was born when I tried to install the 'go' compiler over an existing version.